# Устойчивая сортировка на JS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Это не совсем минимальный пример. Скопировал из своего кода один-в-один. Структура данных:
`this.cellsLayer.children` - массив графическиx примитивов, который отображается на экране. Его нужно сортировать. Каждый элемент этого массива содержит `.object` - ссылку на объект игровой логики для этого элемента.

Вызываю сортировку после модификации любого из объектов игровой логики.

Собственно реализация:

```
this.cellsLayer.children.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  arr[i].index = i;
});
this.cellsLayer.children.sort(function (a, b) {
  var res = a.object.mass - b.object.mass;
  return res == 0 ? a.index <= b.index : res;
});
```

Проблема в том что перекрывающиеся объекты с одинаковыми значениями `object.mass` регулярно (после каждой сортировки) перепрыгивают друг через друга.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так у вас же при одинаковых значениях `mass` и `a.index` меньшем, чем `b.index`, функция сравнения вернет true, которое для целей сортировки будет приведено к 1, и соответственно, в отсортированном массиве `b` окажется перед `a`.

Замените `<=` на `>=` и получите устойчивую сортировку. 
А еще лучше, поскольку функция, возвращающая различные типы данных — это не самый хороший тон программирования, `a.index <= b.index` стоило бы заменить на `a.index - b.index`.

Comment: Остался вопрос почему для Array.prototype.sort() необходимо так извращаться. Разве недостаточно возвращаемого 0 из функции сравнения чтобы sort() не менял местами сравниваемые элементы?

Comment: Потому что `sort()` внутри себя обычно реализуется при помощи алгоритма `QuickSort`, который не является устойчивым.

Answer (score 1):

Для "устойчивой" сортировки нужно при одинаковых елементах вернуть 0. Если больше 1 если меньше -1.

т.е

```
function (a, b) {
  var res = a.object.mass - b.object.mass;
  return res == 0 ? ( a.index <= b.index ? (a.index==b.index)? 0 : false  ):   res;
}
```

Ещё, возвращать вычет можно, что упрощает задачу. return res==0 ? a.index-b.index : res;

Comment: Мой вопрос об устойчивой сортировке посредством JS функции Array.prototype.sort(), для которой по неведомым причинам недостаточно при одинаковых элементах (элементах которые не следует менять местами) просто вернуть 0. Вот и пришлось городить огород с введением дополнительного свойства для каждого элемента - индекса элемента в отсортированном массиве. Просто я слегка ошибся и вместо -1, 0, +1 возвращал true/false при равности основного критерия.