# Сортировка массива объектов по возрастанию

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

У меня есть такой код

```js
let data = [ {"price" : "1000"} , {"price" : "500"} , {"price" : "100"}  ];
data.sort();
console.log(data); 
//должно выйти - [{"price" : "100"},{"price" : "500"},{"price" : "1000"}]
```

и у меня вопрос: Как мне отсортировать по значениям цен?

Скрипт должен сортировать массив объектов по возрастанию цены

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка массива объектов по строковому свойству как по числам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325914/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понятия и не имею как был принят предыдщий ответ, но явно не работает и вот наглядное док-во:

```js
let data = [{
  "price": "1000"
}, {
  "price": "100"
}, {
  "price": "500"
}];
data.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1);
console.log(data);
```

- Во первых, как можно увидеть он просто выводит в том же порядке что и записано в массив
- Во вторых возвращать `-1`, когда элементы равны нельзя. [В этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485851/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js) обсуждалось это

А вот то что вам нужно было на самом деле:

```js
const data = [{
  "price": "1000"
}, {
  "price": "100"
}, {
  "price": "500"
}];

data.sort((a, b) => (+a.price) - (+b.price));
console.log(data);

// Ну или можно записать явное преобразование в число, если читать плюсики не очень удобно

data.sort((a, b) => Number(a.price) - Number(b.price));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: ну я был ссоный и не сразу увидел что он выводит в таком порядке )

Answer (score -1):

```js
let data = [{
  "price": "1000"
}, {
  "price": "500"
}, {
  "price": "100"
}];
data.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Отмечу, что в данном случае придется преобразовать значение к числовому значению, для корректной сортировки.